# List references in python

Tags: python, reference

How can changes in one list be reflected in another?

```
lst = [0, 0]
sublist = [lst[0], lst[0], lst[1], lst[1]]
print sublist
>> [0, 0, 0, 0]
lst[0] = 1
print sublist
>> [0, 0, 0, 0]
# But I would like to
>> [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

How can i get the desired result?
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Lists don't support that. You'll need to find some other way to solve whatever problem you're hoping to solve by doing this.

Comment: Related: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: If you want the effect to propagate, make sure the object is mutable, in your example, you need to make elements of `lst` to be mutable.

Comment: Lists are eager evaluated. There is one really kludgy/dirty thing you can do.
Consider the following `a = 5` then `f = lambda: a` then `b = [f,f,f]`. `b[0]()` will output `5`. But change `a = 7 ` and try `b[0]()` will output 7. In effect what you are doing is "freezing" eager evaluation and evaluating it at runtime based on the value of a.

Comment: Most voted for the wrong comment but on my issue downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all! Got it.

```
lst = [[] for i in range(2)]
sublist = [lst[0], lst[0], lst[1], lst[1]]
print lst
print sublist
lst[0].append(1)
lst[1].append(2)
print lst
print sublist
lst[1][0] = 0
print lst
print sublist

>>[[], []]
>>[[], [], [], []]
>>[[1], [2]]
>>[[1], [1], [2], [2]]
>>[[1], [0]]
>>[[1], [1], [0], [0]]
```